Can we use selenium for upload file with headless chrome in case the button not is type input?
Here is the code work with case press the button and it show openFileDialog
 var upload = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/a"));
 upload.Click();
 AutoItX3 auto = new AutoItX3();
 auto.WinActivate("Open");
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 auto.Send(ofd.FileName);
 auto.Send("{Enter}");

The ofd.FileName is path of the file that I picked from C# form before.
So the problem here is I can not use:
element.SendKey(path);

directly to the button html type <input> while it is in headless mode.
So can it work to upload File in this situation without showing the chrome window?
Already search for result but only show solution in case button type is input tag

you can use javascriptexecutor class

you should include the markup of the form you are dealing with... you may need to generate certain events using javascript executor.  (but usually not... you can probably still use sendkeys and submit() methods...)
